# Databind in CheckBoxList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, checkboxlist

I have a database table as `Parts` and and i'm displaying items in this table in a `CheckBoxList`. Then user can select appropriate parts when adding a new vehicle. when user submit page, data save in a table called `Vehicle_Parts` with `vehicle_id` and `part_id`.

Now i'm creating a edit page for above added items. i'm passing `vehicle_id` in `QueryString`. in my edit page i want to display all the parts from `Parts` table and also need to check the check boxes of parts which user selected when creating a vehicle in adding a new vehicle.

how can i do this ?

I'm using entity framework 4.1

Comment: You can do this by adding an extra column for parts status. When you add or save the data first time, you store checked and unchecked status for all the parts in parts table. And when you are showing your data in edit menu, simply read the checked and unchecked status to selected parts by the user.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then tell me so that I could provide you the solution.